# How to stop figure repeatedly popping up after closing animation

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure

Lately I've started to make a crank mechanism animation. The animation works well, but when I tried to close the `Figure 1` window it just keeps popping up.

I don't know how to stop this?

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;
radius=2;
vzdOdKliky=6;
bod1=[0,0];
axis(gca, 'equal');
mezera=[-4,8,-4,8];
axis(mezera);
speed=1;
for time=1:200
    theta=speed*(time/10);
    bod2=radius*[cos(theta),sin(theta)];
    alfa=asin(radius*sin(theta)/vzdOdKliky);
    bod3=[(radius*cos(theta)+vzdOdKliky*cos(alfa)) 0];
    klika=line([bod1(1),bod2(1)],[bod1(2),bod2(2)]);
    klouzM=line([bod2(1),bod3(1)],[bod2(2),bod3(2)]);
    trajB2=viscircles([0,0],radius,'LineStyle',':');
    kruhB1=viscircles(bod1,0.3);
    kruhB2=viscircles(bod2,0.3);
    kruhB3=viscircles(bod3,0.2);
    pause(0.001);
    delete(klika);
    delete(kruhB1);
    delete(kruhB2);
    delete(kruhB3);
    delete(klouzM);
end
```

Comment: CTRL+C works I guess

Comment: Do you mean that you try to close the figure before the animation is done? If so, the problem is that you need to cancel the execution (Ctrl+C), because closing the window does not stop the loop of cancel the execution.
If you want the code to stop running when you close the window, you can use the figure handle:
`f1=figure; for time=1:200, if ~ishandle(f1), break; else, % The rest of the loop;  end, end`

Comment: You can specify a handle to the figure, then in the beginning of each iteration put a condition that will break if the handle in no longer exist.

Answer (score 7):

**Your loop continues regardless of whether you've closed the figure or not.**

Include a check on the figure's existence each loop like so:

```
% Open figure and store to variable for checking later
fg = figure;
% ... your setup code ...
for time = 1:200
    % Check if the figure still exists
    if ~isvalid(fg)
        % Exit looping, figure has been closed
        break
    end
    % ... other code in the loop ...
end
```

If you wanted to be less elegant, you could always hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate your script.

Comment: I did not know this and its enormously useful for me. Great!

Comment: @AnderBiguri Glad it was useful! The `isvalid` command also works for handle objects if you ever do any OOP work and want to test for the existence of an object